# Is there a way to use AVSpeechSynthesizer as a Notification sound?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, avspeechsynthesizer

I'd like to have a Notification trigger and speak a line of text. UILocalNotification accepts an external file. Is there a way to use AVSpeechSynth instead?